# bitwise OR int and char

Tags: c++, c

I have a value that I know is less than 16 (no more than 4 bits) in an `int`. I want to bitwise-OR it into a `char`. Can I do this:

```
c |= i;
```

or will that depend on endianness? If it is a problem, will this:

```
c |= (char)i;
```

solve it?

Comment: Suggestion: choose a language and stick with it. Do not try to write multi-language source files: it is **very** hard work :)

Comment: @pmg In this particular case, both C and C++ are relevant, and have the same answer.

Comment: @pmg I am writing c++, but since this area is the same for c, I included it.

Comment: Rule of thumb: in 99% of the cases where you find yourself doing bitwise arithmetic on signed integer types, it means that you are confused and don't know what you are doing. Even more so if you do bitwise arithmetic on `char`, because `char` could be either signed or unsigned, it is impl. defined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin Since I am only using the bit values, never the integer value of the `char` (and no left-shifts), it doesn't make a difference if it is signed or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Endianness never matters when doing arithmetic, it only matters when dealing with values (larger than 1 `char`) in some other way, i.e. when using char-pointers to traverse buffers holding larger values, for instance.

In your case, there is no need to cast, automatic arithmetic promotion will make sure it's all fine. The code:

```
char c = 0;
int  i =3;

c |= i;
```

is equivalent to

```
c = c | i;
```

The expression will be computed as `int`, and then converted back down for storage.

Comment: thanks @unwind. I was struggling with how to explain this, unicorns and all.

Comment: I think in his question, `c` was the `char`, and `i` the `int`.

Comment: And endianness really never matters, for anything.

Comment: Now explain what happens when one of the integers has a negative value (taking into account "sign + magnitude" vs. "2's complement" vs. whatever else the implementation may have felt like defining). :-)

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks, I had swapped `c` and `i`. Not sure about your disregard for endianness, though. I've seen it matter. :)

Comment: @unwind I've seen it matter too, once or twice.  But always in system level code (and implementation of `modf` in the C standard library, for example, where I had to extract the exponent from a double).  It's generally not an issue.

Comment: @unwind And if you really want to be verbose: `c |= i;` is the equivalent of `c = static_cast<char>( static_cast<int>( c ) | i );`.  Conceptually, at least, the compiler will convert the `char` into an `int` before doing the `|`, and then convert the results back to a `char`.  (There is, of course, a good chance that the compiler will recognize that all these type conversions have no impact on the results, and forgo them.  At least on a machine that can do a hardware or on a `char`; most can't.)

Answer (score 3):

it has nothing to do with endianness. `c |= i;` will simply work.

Comment: @DanielFischer Pretty sure it's either magic, unicorns or both!

Comment: The why is because that is the way computers work.  The only real question here that I can see is why anyone might think that it wouldn't.

Comment: @JamesKanze The reason I thought it might not is if the `char` gets `OR`ed with the LSB. But now that I am writing this, I am not sure why I would have ever thought that.

Comment: what considered LSB/MSb does not depend on endianness either.

Comment: Effectively, the `char` will be or'ed with the LSB.  Regardless of where that byte is in the memory layout of the `int`.

Comment: I think this answer assumes that you actually know what endianess means. Endianess only applies to integers of several bytes, and the type here is a char, endianess does not apply.

Comment: @Elazar In my comment, I meant first byte, not really the LSB. As I wrote, I am getting less and less sure of what was going through my head.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do something like this, which prevents against sign-extension if the destination is wider (has more bits) than the source:

`c = c | (0x0f & i);`

It also serves as a reminder of which bits in the source are the target bits to extract.

Comment: Seeing the OP wants four bits, shouldn't that be `c = c | (0x0f & i);`?

Comment: On some systems, c |= i where c is wider than i and i is signed, will result in c being sign-extended if the value in i is negative.  This will prevent that.

Comment: The best practice is to never ever do bitwise arithmetic on signed numbers. In this specific case, it isn't an issue. But since you mention sign-extension, the safest possible way to write this expression is `c = c | (0x0fu & i);`, because it will force the implicit type promotion rules of C to ensure that the result is unsigned (and then truncated into a char).

Comment: When using the mask, I don't think that the unsigned specifier 'u' is required.

Comment: The `u` will convert the literal 0x0f to type `unsigned int`. This will in turn convert the result of the operation `0x0fu & i` to unsigned int. Which will in turn convert the result of `c | (0x0fu & i)` to unsigned int. If you don't know how implicit type promotion works in C, then never ever consider bitwise arithmetic on signed integer types. You are going to produce floods of very subtle bugs.

Comment: Yes what you're saying is true, but in the case that the destination is wider than the source, it doesn't matter.  The mask will produce only the bits that you care about.

Comment: @Lundin The best practice _is_ not to do bitwise operations on signed types.  And `c` and `i` should be `unsigned char` and `unsigned int`.  But since he explicitly said that he's only using the four low order bits, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -3):

You are better off using `c |= (char)(i);`

Comment: Why?  It looks like just extra noise to me.  (He might want to precede the `c |= i;` with an assert: `assert( (i & ~0x0F) == 0 );`, for example.  But that's a different issue.

Comment: I tried it on both big and little endian machines and the result is the same.  So, it does not really matter.  I prefer to do it with the typecast to remind myself that I knew that I am mixing the two types.

Comment: This cast only shows that you don't know how implicit type promotion works in C. The cast is superfluous clutter and does nothing. Print `sizeof(c | (char)some_int)`, it will be the size of an int. If you want a typecast to remind yourself of something, you should have written `c = (char)(c | i);` which would at least have been meaningful.